# I need Code How to start process in in a specific time

Tags: c#, timer, process

**
I need Code How to start process in in a specific time
for exmple

```
**

if  --- date "01/10/1991"  then 

    process.start

    end if
```

**

Comment: u better add more details

Comment: Where/when is your code running

Comment: want to run process, provided the time is specified by day, year and month

Comment: Any Process  for example  Notepad.exe  Start after 1/28/2021

Comment: Like Windows Task Scheduler or you want to implement your own service?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this test condition:

```
if ( DateTime.Today == new DateTime(2021, 01, 10) )
  RunShell(filePath)/*.WaitForExit()*/;
```

[DateTime.Today Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today)

[DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32) Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Having for example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

static public Process RunShell(string filePath, string arguments = "")
{
  var process = new Process();
  try
  {
    process.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    process.Start();
    return process;
  }
  catch ( Exception ex )
  {
    Console.WriteLine or MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + filename);
  }
}
```

Where `filePath` is the full path of a file or a web link for example.

[Process.Start Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start)